# VBA Name a Sheet with ComboBox

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I have a commandButton which opens a UserForm to add a new Worksheet.
In this Userform is a ComboBox, where i can choose the machine type.

Now i want to create a new Worksheet with the Name of the machine type which was selected in the ComboBox.

This is my Code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Sheets("Sheet1").Copy Before:=Sheets(10)
    ws.Name = ComboBox1
    [UserForm1].Hide
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ComboBox1.List = Array("Machine Type 1", "Machine Type 2")
End Sub
```

Is there a way to create a new sheet, which is a copy from Sheet1 and name it like the machine type from the ComboBox1?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below, see notes in the code's comments:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Sheets("Sheet1").Copy Before:=Sheets(10)
    Set ws = ActiveSheet ' <-- you need to set the worksheet object to the latest copied sheet
    ws.Name = ComboBox1.Value '<-- now you can modify the name using the worksheet object
    Me.Hide '<-- hide the user-form        
End Sub
```

Comment: That´s it .. Thank you very much.

Comment: of course i will, but you have to wait 2 more minutes :)

Comment: @diem_L LOL , I forgot :)

Comment: what do i have to add when i want to create a Sheet with the same name? so that the second sheet would name "Machine Type 1 (2)"? .. hope it´s okay if i ask here

Comment: @diem_L  you should open a new post,add your modified code. So other users besides me can help, also not to make a mess of this thread

Answer (score 1):

use

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Copy Before:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = ComboBox1.Value
    Me.Hide
End Sub
```

Comment: Explain how this helps to solve the problem and what the OP did do wrong.

Comment: OP has already everything he needs. and even more (two unnecessary code lines and one unnecessary variable)

Comment: Yes I know, but I think you should add a little explaination to your awnser. Like the accepted anwser did in his snippet using comment lines.

Comment: the explanation you require is right in the accepted answer

Comment: BTW the down voter can refer to this [Help topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) to review its action

Comment: I didn't downvote the anwser. See this topic: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366404/does-this-answer-meets-the-criteria It probaly came from one the readers. In my opinion it doens't need a downvote.